# parsed json object only returning last element

Tags: json, jquery-mobile, getjson

looping through getJSON results to display json object in `<li>` - only returns last element - json object has full results?  looping through data[i] should give me all?

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
    <link href="http://jqmdesigner.appspot.com/gk/lib/jquery.mobile/1.4.2/flatui/jquery.mobile.flatui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <title>get the html from a website</title>
    <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON("tt_json.php", function(data){
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                $.each(data[i], function(key, val) {
                    //alert(key + ":" + val); 
                    $('#myUL').html("<li>" + key + " : " + val + "</li>");  
                });
            } 
        });

    </script>
</head>    
<body>          
<!-- Page: home  -->
    <div id="home" data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
        <h3>GET WEB DATA</h3>
        </div>
        <div role="main1" id="mainone" class="ui-content"> 
            <ul data-role='listview' id='myUL' data-inset='true' class='ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow'>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div role="main" id="mainzero" class="ui-content"> 
        </div>
    </div>           
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you seem to set the html tag with id  `myUL` in the loop of your javascript function. this overwrites the inner html of that tag each time. Try to add the `li` element instead of overwriting.

Comment: changed `$('#myUL').html` to `$('#myUL').append` that fixed it, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.